# How to capture a still image from digital video?

Tags: windows, video-capture

I'd like to get a still image from a digital video I've taken.

A quick search has revealed these two possibilities,

- [capture-still-image-video](http://www.ehow.com/how_2142404_capture-still-image-video.html)  which uses vlc player
- [extract-still-image-from-video](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/extract-still-image-from-video/) which uses Imagegrab

Any suggestions on which might be better or alternatives?

I'd be using Windows OS

**Update**
In the end I used Windows Live Movie Maker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like VLC and have it installed so for ease of use I would probably use that. If I didn't find those results satisfactory I would probably attempt to use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) with one of the [autobuilds from tripp](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/).

Syntax as follows:

> ffmpeg -i foo.avi -ss 00:01:43 -t 1 -s 1280x720 -f mjpeg bar.jpg

That should take one shot at 1 minute 43 seconds and output a jpg, at 1280x720

Answer (score 1):

VLC has a snapshot item on the Tools menu, which will take a snapshot of the video and save it as a bmp file.

> How can I take screenshots?
>
> To take a snapshot of the video
>   displayed by VLC, you just need to
>   press the pre-defined snapshot hotkey:
>
> ```
> * Windows / Linux / Unix: Ctrl+Alt+S
> * Mac OS X: Command+Alt+s
> ```
>
> To change it, go to Preferences ->
>   Interface -> Hotkeys settings, check
>   Advanced options, and set Take video
>   snapshot.
>
> You can also take a snaphot via the
>   menu Video -> Snapshot.
>
> To change the snapshot format or
>   directory, go to Preferences -> Video.

http://www.videolan.org/support/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

"Alt-Prt Scr" with the video player's window active to copy the window to clipboard.

"Shift-Prt Scr" will capture the entire desktop.

Paste it into your favorite image editor (ie: MS Paint) for cropping, etc.

Hope that helps...

Comment: snapshots of videos using overlays will result in a big black snapshot if this is used.

Comment: True, but since there was lack of detail as to which kind of 'digital video' was in question I figured I'd offer the easiest answer, as it's often an option the user may not be aware their 'Windows OS' has.